# How do I deal with blank variables in batch?

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

```
Set /P Input=[%CD%]
For /F "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%A In ('Echo %Input%') do (
   Set "Root=%%A"
   Set "Function=%%B"
   Set "Execute=%%C"
)
If %Root%==File Goto File
Goto Start

REM These are the File.Commands
:File
If %Function%==Run Goto File_Run
If %Function%==TestFor Goto File_TestFor
```

In this program I sometimes have the variable "Function" blank and when I do it closes because it sets the variable to "ECHO is off", and then when I try to compare it just in case it isn't blank but it is blank, it closes. How do I fix this?

When I run this program and "Function" is empty the output is:
Goto was unexpected at this time.

Then it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doubleqoutes in your `IF`-lines to avoid syntax errors:

```
If "%Function%"=="Run" Goto File_Run
```

you may want to add a line:

```
If "%Function%"=="" Goto Empty_Function
```